# Multiply beta coefficients from two different models

Tags: regression, least-squares, regression-coefficients, negative-binomial-distribution, mediation

I have a count outcome with a heavy right skew that is modeled with a negative binomial. I have a continuous mediator that is modeled with OLS. 
We're attempting a method of causal mediation analyses that calls for the product of coefficients across these models to estimate the natural indirect effect (the effect of exposure on outcome mediated through the mediator). A causal diagram can be found below.

`glm.nb((outcome) ~ exposure + mediator + [set of covariates], data = dat)`; 
Here I save the beta coefficient for mediator (we'll call it B1)

`lm(mediator ~ exposure + [set of covariates], data = dat)`; 
Here I save the beta coefficient for exposure (we'll call it B2)

Can I multiply B1*B2 despite the differences in model form? If not, what can I do to make them compatible for multiplication?

[image]

Comment: Sure -- but whether that has any meaning at all will depend on the models, the data, and how you intend to interpret it.  Could you provide some of those details?

Comment: Added the details.